# Bluetooth keyboard and mouse keep popping up and then going away

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

My apple bluetooth aluminum keyboard and mouse keep popping up and then going away. They don't even have time to connect. I'm just wondering why that is.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to bluetooth set up a new device, you need to put 0000 as PIN options.

Eventually the popping up and going away thing just stopped, for some reason.